# How can I exclude any location returned by maps API that is not a town, city, region or country?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I was going through the geocoding and reverse geocoding API from google (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types) but am a bit confused.

When my user searches for a location on my page connected to google maps API - if the user chooses anything which is not a village, town, region, country - I want to throw an appropriate message.

e.g. If user types Taj Mahal, google auto-completes to "Taj Mahal, Agra, Uttar Pradesh, India" I want to throw a message "You can only choose village, town, region, country. Would you like to select Agra instead?"

So in short

- User should **not** be allowed to choose anything at the street level e.g. 23, Park lane, London
- User should **only** be allowed to choose something equal or higher than a village/town/city level. Having said that I am working where will national parks come.

Is there some utility online where I can put an address and check what the google maps API returns as its values - e.g. whats the short name, administrative_area_level_1 etc

Comment: the geocoder returns all these informations, how hard could it be to inspect the results in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what *type* of `types` you want to catch and propose as a replacement.

Check the following <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ehPup/)</kbd> for a demo.

I am filtering the results against the following types:

```
var types = [
    'locality',
    'postal_town',
    'country'
];
```

Of course you will need to adjust these filters to your needs, but it should give you an idea of how to achieve what you want.